# Retain unique columns when merging and grouping Pandas DataFrames similar to using ID= in PROC MEANS in SAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have two DataFrames that I want to merge and perform a groupby operation.  I can retain unique values for "Actual Manager" and "Proposed Manager" by using the max function.  This seems to work like the ID= statement in a SAS PROC MEANS data step.  I shouldn't be able to do this because these categorical columns aren't ordered. In fact, I get an error message to this effect when I increase the number of columns in the values3 list below. Any suggestions on how to code this properly?

Here is my Python code.

```
    import openpyxl
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    
    act_data =[['G3603','JOHN SMITH','', 250000.0]]  
    bud_data =[['G3603','','TOM JONES',260000.0]]
                  
    # Create the pandas DataFrames
    df_actual = pd.DataFrame(act_data, columns=['Project','Actual Manager','Proposed Manager', 'Actual'])                                      
    df_fcast  = pd.DataFrame(bud_data, columns=['Project','Actual Manager','Proposed Manager', 'Budget']) 
    
    values1 = ['Project','Actual Manager','Proposed Manager']
    values2 = ['Project']
    values3 = ['Actual Manager','Proposed Manager','Actual','Budget',]
    both=pd.merge(df_actual, df_fcast, on = values1, how = 'outer')
    both2=both.groupby(values2)[values3].max()
    print(both)
    print(both2)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MHJY.png)

Comment: your groupby result is not assigned to any variable or to both, and right after groupby you are listing out both DF.  That might be why, you are seeing two rows. Eliminate the both statement after the groupby

Comment: I tried this: both2=both.groupby(values1)[values2].max().  print(both2) Looks like I still have two rows.

Comment: Looks like this worked : 
#Merge the data                                                                                                   
values1 = ['Project','Actual Manager','Proposed Manager']
values2 = ['Project']
values3 = ['Actual Manager','Proposed Manager','Actual','Budget']
both=pd.merge(df_actual, df_fcast, on = values1, how = 'outer')
both2=both.groupby(values2)[values3].max()
print(both2)